# Difficulty with passing arrays and manipulating data in arrays (Homework) c#

Tags: c#, arrays, c#-4.0

So I am doing a Homework assignment for c#. The assignment requires the use of 2 arrays, one to hold names and the other to hold scores. We are then to calculate the average score, display the below average scores, and display the scores according to name. I am having a significant amount of difficulty passing the arrays by reference/value in order to use the data in them and maintain my code using separate modules. The arrays have to hold up to 100 individual pieces of data.

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] playerNames = new string[100];
            int[] playerScores = new int [100];
            int numPlayers = 0;
            double averageScore;

            DisplayData(playerNames);

        }

        static void InputData(string[] playerNames, int[] playerScores, ref int numPlayers)
        {
            string playerName;

            do
            {
                int i = 0;
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the name of the player...Enter \"Q to exit...");
                playerName = Console.ReadLine();
                if (playerName == "Q" || playerName == "q")
                    Console.WriteLine("No further user input needed...\n");
                else
                    playerNames[i] = playerName;
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter the score of the player...");
                    int playerScore = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    playerScores[i] = playerScore;
                    numPlayers += i;
                    i++;
            }
            while (playerName != "Q");

        }

        static void CalculateAverageScore(int[] playerScores, ref int averageScore)
        {
            InputData(playerScores);
            InputData(ref numPlayers);
            int averageScores = 0;
            averageScores = playerScores / numPlayers;





        }
```

The biggest question I have is that I cannot seem to pass the array data. I am plagued by "No overload method for "Input Data" or whatever method I am using. So I'm curious as to how I can pass the array data to another method.

Comment: Do you have a specific question? For general feedback, you may want to put this up on the Code Review SE.

Comment: You should probably read Jon Skeet's [Parameter passing in C#](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html) Also you don't really seem to be asking a question

Comment: Can you please be more specific?  " significant amount of difficulty " is not very helpful to readers.

Comment: Sorry, I am frustrated and thought I asked my question. I edited my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this is homework, I won't give you the full answer, but here is a way forward.

Instead of using the `ref` keyword, just pass the array into the method. Have the method return an `int` instead of `void`. Calculate the average within the method and have the final line of the method return the int that you've calculated

```
static int CalculateAverageScore(int[] playerScores)
{
    // calculate average

    return average; // the int you've calculated.
}
```

Call the method from the main, when you need to acquire the average.

Also, are you missing some braces `{ }` for the 6 lines that come after your `else` statement?

Comment: I didn't even notice the missing curly braces. Thank you! The biggest issue I'm having here. Is how do I pass the array and then manipulate the data so I can multiply and divide the data in the array?

Comment: well, to calculate the average, don't you only have to read each element in the array, 1 at a time? In other words, if you've already got your array of data, you don't have to change any of that data, you just have to read each element, individually.

Comment: to make things simpler, what you could do is: (1) start with arrays that only have 2 elements. (2) instead of getting the data from user input, start by putting fake or "dummy" data into your program. Use these two simplification strategies until you've confirmed that some of your code is correct, then add more elements in the arrays and add the user-input feature. Does that make sense?

Comment: in other words, it really helps to build up a program with 1 small step at a time. Build 1 really small part of it, verify that it is correct, then add another part.